# Mod Rewrite with multiple values

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do something like this...Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)^/(.*)^/(.*)$ /$1/$2.php?page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Basically I want to be able to put in something like /item1/item2/item3 and have those values in $1, $2, and $3 etc....

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.*`, try using `.+`.  Also be sure to consider there may be a trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/$ /$1/$2.php?page=$3 [l,qsa]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /$1/$2.php?page=$3 [l,qsa]
```

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the `^` is REGEX for ~ "start at the beginning of a string" so it should only be used once in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /$1/$2.php?page=$3 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

> When a substitution occurs for a new
>   URL, this module has to re-inject the
>   URL into the server processing. To be
>   able to do this it needs to know what
>   the corresponding URL-prefix or
>   URL-base is. By default this prefix is
>   the corresponding filepath itself. But
>   at most websites URLs are NOT directly
>   related to physical filename paths, so
>   this assumption will usually be wrong!
>   There you have to use the RewriteBase
>   directive to specify the correct
>   URL-prefix.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase

So maybe you have to set `RewriteBase`. For example you can set it to the root directory:

```
RewriteBase \
```

Also, you can't use more than one `^` in your pattern as it means 'start position of the string'.